# Bézier curve from three different y values

Tags: bezier-curve

So I want to graph the Bézier curve below, but all I can find on how to do it is if two of the points are on the same y coordinate. How would I do it for this? Would I have to create the bottom part of the parabola from two of the same y coordinates, then add another segment to make it look like the one below?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5d46.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.
You can have a look at 
[the starter tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) 
to familiarize yourself further with the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quadratic Bézier segment $S$ is defined by two endpoints
$A$ and $C$ and one control point $B$:

\begin{align}
S(t)&=A\,(1-t)^2+2\,B\,(1-t)\,t+C\,t^2
,\quad t\in[0,1],\\
S(0)&=A,\quad S(1)=C
.
\end{align}

Given the coordinates of the two endpoints and any other
point $P=S(\tau)$, $\tau\in(0,1)$,

\begin{align}
 P&=S(\tau)=A\,(1-\tau)^2+2\,B\,(1-\tau)\,\tau+C\,\tau^2,
\end{align}
the control point $B$ is found as

\begin{align}
 B&=\tfrac1{2\,\tau\,(1-\tau)}(P-A\,(1-\tau)^2-C\,\tau^2)
 .
\end{align}

Dealing with the graphs of the form $y(x)=a_2\,x^2+a_1\,x+a_0$,
the required parameter $\tau$ is found as
\begin{align}
\tau&=\frac{P_x-A_x}{C_x-A_x}
.
\end{align}

For example, given two endpoints 
$A=(0, 575)$, $C=(20,2375)$ and
a third point $P=(15, 1025)$, we have

\begin{align}
\tau&=\frac{15-0}{20-0}=0.75,\\
B&=(10, -925)
.
\end{align}

[image]